# Adverb phrase or prepositional phrase?

Tags: adverbs, prepositional-phrases

If I have the following sentence:

"In mid-August, Gignac flew with Soffer on his private jet to Aspen to discuss the hotel purchase."

Focusing in on the "In mid-August," part in terms of its form, would that be better classified as an adverb phrase due to its being an element of time or a prepositional phrase due to its being introducted by the preposition "In" ?

Comment: *In mid-August* is a prepositional phrase functioning adverbially to modify the verb *flew* (flew when? flew in mid-August).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This phrase is both prepositional and adverbial. Some prepositional phrases are adverbial. Such as "In the morning" or "In the middle of the night."

Comment: Right. _Prepositional_ is part of its form -- it starts with a preposition. _Adverbial_ is part of its function -- it works as a temporal adverb in the sentence. Form and function are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: When I hear "adverbial" I think function, for form I go with "adverb phrase". In this light I think in terms of form, prepositional makes the most sense. This website then mixes adverb phrase and adverbial together and gives "in the springtime" as an example, so that is all kinds of confusing: https://completeenglishgrammar.com/adverbial-phrases-time-place-and-frequency-including-word-order/

Comment: I very much prefer the term 'adjunct' to 'adverbial'. I think it is very unsatisfactory to have a function term that is morphologically derived from a category term. Adverb is a word category, and adverb phrase (a phrase headed by an adverb) the corresponding phrase category. Adverbial is a function and may be realised by an AdvP (_He spoke quickly_), a PP (_He spoke with enthusiasm_), an NP (_He’s speaking this evening_). AdvPs do not always function as adjuncts: they may function as modifier in AdjPs (_It was quite amazingly expensive_), etc.

Comment: ... cont   Adverbial phrase is quite often used for any phrase functioning as adverbial and hence likely to be confused with adverb phrase.